# Alias does not take effect when I use Vim to execute external commands

Tags: shell, vim

Aliases don't take effect when I use Vim to execute external commands, for example:

```
:! ll
```

I want it to support aliases like normal shells do.

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: bash...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "normal shell". You have "interactive shells" and "non-interactive shells", which differ, among other things, by what `*rc` file they source at startup and by *whether aliases are expanded or not*. And there are other types, even.

By default Vim uses a *non-interactive shell* for `:!` and `$ man bash` as the following to say about aliases in non-interactive shells:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the  expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

Now, you *could* try to play with `shopt` or try to convince Vim to use an interactive shell with `:help 'shellcmdflag'` but these don't sound like solutions to me.

The only proper solution, IMO, is to turn your aliases into actual shell scripts, somewhere in your `$PATH`, where they will be accessible to all kinds of shells.

--- EDIT ---

FWIW, I don't like the suggestion made in `:help :!` because…

- As illustrated in the other answer, it creates other problems which in turn requires solutions and so on.
- The "shell" in which `:!` commands are executed is a very dumb one that is not made at all for interactive stuff (no colors, etc.).
- I much prefer to suspend Vim and end up in a proper shell than to execute lots of commands in the bastardized `:!`.

  And there's even `:help :terminal` nowadays if that's your thing.
- I find it a lot cleaner, portable, and scalable to create proper shell scripts in general.

That said, I still have a bunch of aliases, like everyone, but none of them is of any use in a `:!` context so there is no point a) adding `-i` to `shellcmdflag` or b) turning them into scripts:

```
alias fgrep='LC_ALL=C fgrep -nsH --color=auto'
alias flush='sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder'
alias g='git'
alias grep='LC_ALL=C grep -nsH --color=auto'
alias la='ls -alhGF --color=auto'
alias ld='ls -dlhGF --color=auto *'
alias ll='ls -lhGF --color=auto'
alias majports='sudo port selfupdate && port outdated && sudo port upgrade outdated && sudo port uninstall inactive && sudo port uninstall rleaves && sudo port clean all'
alias mgc='magento-cloud'
alias python='python2.7'
alias tigb='tig blame'
alias tigd='tig show'
alias tigg='tig grep'
alias tigl='tig log'
alias tigs='tig status'
alias up='cd ..'
alias vim='mvim -v'
alias webshare='python2.7 -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()"'
```

`:!` is just not a good enough environment for running interactive commands.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your rationale. I agree with you in principle although the only problem using an interactive shell creates is having to type `fg` when you're done. Certainly inconvenient but some people may buy in. I would also have believed you use aliases even if you had not shared *all* of them. I flatter myself in believing you put the Python 2.7 ones in there to annoy me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what romainl writes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78250848/796259), Vim's own [`:help :!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A%21) suggests the following:

> On Unix the command normally runs in a non-interactive
> shell.  If you want an interactive shell to be used
> (to use aliases) set 'shellcmdflag' to "-ic".

That would be `:set shellcmdflag=-ic`.

The caveat is that your shell will not terminate after running your command but prompt you for input instead. You'll have to `fg` to return to Vim. I would guess that's why romainl discarded it as a solution.

FWIW, I wrote a tiny alias a while ago which will return me to Vim when I type `fg` regardless of whether I'm in the shell through Vim's `:shell` or `:terminal` commands or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>:

```
alias fg="[[ -v VIM ]] && exit || fg"
```

This will work for `:!` with `'shellcmdflag'` set to "-ic" as well.